# touch event on image switcher

Tags: android, touch, imageswitcher

i have this code with me and it is running successfully but i want to add touch event on it for changing of image and also for zoom in and zoom out effect....
this is my code:

```
package com.conn;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory;

public class image_slider extends Activity implements ViewFactory {

    Integer pics[] = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d,
            R.drawable.e };

    ImageSwitcher iSwitcher;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        iSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.ImageSwitcher01);
        iSwitcher.setFactory(this);
        iSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in));
        iSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out));

        Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                iSwitcher.setImageResource(pics[arg2]);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context ctx;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            ctx = c; 
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return pics.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

            ImageView iView = new ImageView(ctx);
            iView.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
            iView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            iView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            return iView;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View makeView() {
        ImageView iView = new ImageView(this);
        iView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        iView.setLayoutParams(new 
                ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        iView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
        return iView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through links below it has the all features which you required.

PinchZooming

http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/wiki/PinchImageView
http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/

One finger Zooming

http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/

Hope this helps.

I have modified the class as per your needs.. use this PinchImageView instead of ImageView..so simple

Check this out here ...http://pastebin.com/eRH2D2nF

Thanks..
Giri

Comment: thanks for the help bt it not worked really..can u implement those things for me in my code by editing it.........?

Comment: check my latest ans.its have link for modified code as per your link

Comment: it might be so simple but for a new user like me its somewhat a difficult job...because i have not used touch event even a single time yet....can u edit my code and rectify that....?it will be easy for me to understand as a beginner.....